# JS: check whether default value have been altered

Tags: javascript

is it possible to check whether default value (set using `value="abcdef"`) of a field with `id="someidset"` have changed without having info about this default value? Hope it's kind of clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [`defaultValue` property](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/defaultValueSyntaxandNote.htm). It should work for most types of `<input />` elements. Just check it against the `value` property.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/BqZmG/).

Comment: `defaultValue` will probably work but AFAIK it is not part of any standard.

Answer (score 2):

When you update the content of an element, the `value` property changes. However, the `value` attribute does not.  This means that, presuming the `value` was defined in the `value` attribute in the original HTML, you can compare the two to see if the one has changed:

```
var el = document.getElementById('someidset');
if (el.value != el.getAttribute('value')) {
    // value has changed
}
```

Note that this will only reliably work with `type="text"` inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are attributes and properties.

```
var someInput = document.getElementById('someInput');
someInput.value;                 // inputs value right now
someInput.getAttribute('value'); // inputs value set at start
```

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wVazC/
change the value right after the alert and wait 10 seconds

Comment: @Neal I've modified your answer a little to make the difference more obvious. I hope it's acceptable.

Comment: @McRonald, @pst removed my demo for some reason